# C++ stringstream read in fixed length string to char array

Tags: c++, stringstream

Given data format as "int,int,...,int,string,int", is it possible to use stringstream (only) to properly decode the fields?

**[Code]**

```
int main(int c, char** v)
{
    std::string line = "0,1,2,3,4,5,CT_O,6";
    char delimiter[7];
    int id, ag, lid, cid, fid, did, j = -12345;
    char dcontact[4]; // <- The size of <string-field> is known and fixed
    std::stringstream ssline(line);
    ssline >> id >> delimiter[0]
    >> ag >> delimiter[1]
    >> lid >> delimiter[2]
    >> cid >> delimiter[3]
    >> fid >> delimiter[4]
    >> did >> delimiter[5]  // <- should I do something here?
    >> dcontact >> delimiter[6]
    >> j;
    std::cout << id << ":" << ag << ":" << lid << ":" << cid << ":" << fid << ":" << did << ":";
    std::cout << dcontact << "\n";
}
```

*[Output]* `0:1:2:3:4:5:CT_6,0:-45689`, the bolded part shows the stringstream failed to read 4 char only to dcontact. `dcontact` actually hold more than 4 chars, leaving `j` with garbage data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no specific overload of `operator >> (istream&, char[N])` for N and there is for `char*` so it sees that as the best match. The overload for char* reads to the next whitespace character so it doesn't stop at the comma.

You could wrap your dcontact in a struct and have a specific overload to read into your struct. Else you could use read, albeit it breaks your lovely chain of `>>` operators.

```
ssline.read( dcontact, 4 );
```

will work at that point.

To read up to a delimiter, incidentally, you can use `getline`. (`get` will also work but `getline` free-function writing to a `std::string` will mean you don't have to guess the length).

(Note that other people have specified to use `get` rather than `read`, but this will fail in your case as you do not have an extra byte at the end of your `dcontact` array for a null terminator. IF you want `dcontact` to be null-terminated then make it 5 characters and use 'get` and the null will be appended for you).

Comment: thanks for your information, i also searched the reference about stringstream.read()

Comment: Since the length of the string is known you can use `std::setw(4)`, as in `ssline >> std::setw(4) >> dcontact;`

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more robust (handles the `','` delimiter correctly):

```
template <char D>
std::istream& delim(std::istream& in)
{
  char c;
  if (in >> c && c != D) in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
  return in;
}

int main()
{
  std::string line = "0,1,2,3,4,5,CT_O,6";
  int id, ag, lid, cid, fid, did, j = -12345;
  char dcontact[5]; // <- The size of <string-field> is known and fixed
  std::stringstream ssline(line);
  (ssline >> id >> delim<','>
          >> ag >> delim<','>
          >> lid >> delim<','>
          >> cid >> delim<','>
          >> fid >> delim<','>
          >> did >> delim<','> >> std::ws
          ).get(dcontact, 5, ',') >> delim<','>
          >> j;
  std::cout << id << ":" << ag << ":" << lid << ":"
            << cid << ":" << fid << ":" << did << ":";
            << dcontact << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Neet use of a manipulator to handle the separators, but note that `istream::get` doesn't skip white space, regardless of the `skipws` flag.  Unlike `>>`, which is used for everything else.  So the input will fail if it has `"...5, CT_0, 6"`.

Comment: +1 because you remembered to fix dcontact to be 5 characters to use get. Of course you assume that it is intended to be a string and thus have such a terminator.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  int main(int c, char** v) {
    string line = "0,1,2,3,4,5,CT_O,6";
    char delimiter[7];
    int id, ag, lid, cid, fid, did, j = -12345;
    char dcontact[5]; // <- The size of <string-field> is known and fixed

    stringstream ssline(line);

    ssline >> id >> delimiter[0]
            >> ag >> delimiter[1]
            >> lid >> delimiter[2]
            >> cid >> delimiter[3]
            >> fid >> delimiter[4]
            >> did >> delimiter[5];

    ssline.get(dcontact, 5);

    ssline >> delimiter[6]
            >> j;
    std::cout << id << ":" << ag << ":" << lid << ":" << cid << ":" << fid << ":" << did << ":";
    std::cout << dcontact << "\n" << j;
    }
```

Comment: If you use get you need to edit dcontact to make it 5 characters or it will overflow. get adds a null terminator for you. read does not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `>>` operator for a string
(`std::string` or a C style string) actually implements the
semantics for a word, with a particular definition of word.  The
decision is arbitrary (I would have made it a line), but since
a string can represent many different things, they had to choose
something.

The solution, in general, is not to use `>>` on a string, ever.
Define the class you want (here, probably something like
`Symbol`), and define an operator `>>` for it which respects its
semantics.  You're code will be a lot clearer for it, and you
can add various invarant controls as appropriate.  If you know
that the field is always exactly four characters, you can do
something simple like:

```
class DContactSymbol
{
    char myName[ 4 ];
public:
    //  ...
    friend std::istream&
    operator>>( std::istream& source, DContactSymbol& dest );
    //  ...
};

std::istream&
operator>>( std::istream& source, DContactSymbol& dest )
{
    std::sentry guard( source );
    if ( source ) {
        std::string tmp;
        std::streambuf* sb = source.rdbuf();
        int ch = sb->sgetc();
        while ( source && (isalnum( ch ) || ch == '_') ) {
            tmp += static_cast< char >( ch );
            if ( tmp.size() > sizeof( dest.myName ) ) {
                source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
            }
        }
        if ( ch == source::traits_type::eof() ) {
            source.setstate( std::ios_base::eofbit );
        }
        if ( tmp.size() != sizeof( dest.myName ) ) {
            source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
        }
        if ( source ) {
            tmp.copy( dest.myName, sizeof( dest.myName ) );
        }
    }
    return source;
}
```

(Note that unlike some of the other suggestions, for example
using `std::istream::read`, this one maintains all of the usual
conventions, like skipping leading white space dependent on the
`skipws` flag.)

Of course, if you can't guarantee 100% that the symbol will
always be 4 characters, you should use `std::string` for it, and
modify the `>>` operator accordingly.

And BTW, you seem to want to read four characters into
`dcontact`, although it's only large enough for three (since
`>>` will insert a terminating `'\0'`).  If you read any more
than three into it, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: You can read 4 characters into dcontact safely, it will only be an issue if you treat it as a null-terminated string because it isn't.

read() will put the next 4 bytes from the stream into dcontact, if there are that many left in the stream. You are right that it won't skip whitespace or interpret delimiters. It is just a "dumb" copy.  Sometimes that is what you want - for it to just give you what's there and not try to work out what it thinks you want.

Assuming your program writes the file, you should know what's in it.

Comment: It's a text file.  You can't assume anything about it.  Even if your program wrote it, someone could have edited it since then.  And since he likely needs a class for the type elsewhere, defining a `>>` on it would seem the most natural solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since the length of the string is known you can use `std::setw(4)`, as in

```
ssline >> std::setw(4) >> dcontact >> delimiter[6];
```